# What causes much emptiness at the right side of codeblocks?

Tags: spacing, listings, overleaf, geometry

I am trying to fill the codeblocks to almost all page as symmetrical as possible but something off with regular text and codeblocks placement to the page:
[image]

Snippets from my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

.
.
.

\lstdefinestyle{mitigation}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{mitigationbackground},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{mitigationcolor},
  keywordstyle=\color{mitigationkeyword},
  commentstyle=\color{mytitlecolor},
  numbers=none,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  frame=lines,
  rulecolor=\color{mitigationcolor},
  framesep=8pt,
  xleftmargin=8pt,
  framexleftmargin=8pt,
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  aboveskip=1\baselineskip,
  lineskip=-1pt, % Adjust this value to control line spacing
  escapeinside={(*}{*)}, % Add this line for line breaks in code
}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{mycodebackground},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{mycodecolor},
  keywordstyle=\color{myprotectedcolor},
  commentstyle=\color{mytitlecolor},
  numbers=none,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  frame=lines,
  rulecolor=\color{mycodecolor},
  framesep=8pt,
  xleftmargin=8pt,
  framexleftmargin=8pt,
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  aboveskip=1\baselineskip,
  lineskip=-1pt, % Adjust this value to control line spacing
  escapeinside={(*}{*)}, % Add this line for line breaks in code
}

.
.
.

The code snippet below illustrates a potential File Inclusion vulnerability:
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, label=java-code3, linewidth=0.9\linewidth]
public class FileHandler {
    public String readFile(String fileName) {
        String filePath = "/path/to/files/" + fileName;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line);
        }
        return content.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
        }
    return null;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

In this example, the 'fileName' parameter is directly concatenated into the 'filePath string without proper validation. An attacker could manipulate the 'fileName' parameterto include files outside of the intended directory, leading to unauthorized access t\\ sensitive system files.

Mitigation:
\lstset{style=mitigation}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, label=java-code4, linewidth=0.9\linewidth]
public class FileHandler {
private static final String BASE_PATH = "/path/to/files/";

public String readFile(String fileName) {
    if (!isValidFileName(fileName)) {
        // Handle invalid file name
        return null;
    }

    String filePath = BASE_PATH + fileName;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line);
        }
        return content.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean isValidFileName(String fileName) {
    // Implement validation logic for file name
}

}
\end{lstlisting}
```

P.S: Since this is just for learning to prepare reports with LaTeX, actual code or vulnerability or mitigation doesn't matter as much.

Comment: This ``linewidth=0.9\linewidth` and the 8pts you have also for right margin.

Comment: @yannisl I removed both but didn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: please always providec ode that shows the problem, you have . .. and other things that mean this can not be run, but you have nothing to say the coloured panels should be full width they are just as wide as the code

Comment: @dev0023 If you just change the linewidth=\linewidth you will see the difference. You have a hell of a lot of missing info in your minimal example, all the colors! Please fix so we can run the same example. Also one code block is enough for an example.

Comment: @yannisl yep it worked, thanks. Btw, as you can see i am an amateur on this. Do you have any more tips to make my report prettier? I don't have any hard requirements so I can change a lot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure I got everything from what you have commented and I was just trying to make my code easier to read by removing the first page which works mostly fine. Either way, other commenter's solution worked, so thanks for investing time on my question.

Comment: @dev0023 remember that for most questions it is almost impossible to answer just by reading the code and spotting the error by eye, people need to run it. So yes, make an example without the first page but post the entire test document and show the output from the code posted, then people can test it. It might for example just work for other people and the answer is "update your system " (that is not the case here) or if people can reproduce the problem a test file allows them to debug it and trace tex code.